# Adding a Maybe to a CompositDisposable in RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java2

In my Activity I have the following, which results in the error message **'Error:(190, 35) error: incompatible types: MaybeObserver cannot be converted to Disposable'**. I expected this to work because I've been doing something similar with a Completable and a DisposableCompletableObserver combination. How can I use a Maybe with a CompositeDisposable in RxJava2?

```
private final CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

// ...

String id = authManager.getUserID();

Maybe maybe = userManager.getUser(id);

disposables.add(maybe
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeWith(new DisposableMaybeObserver() {
                           @Override
                           public void onSuccess(Object o) {

                           }

                           @Override
                           public void onError(Throwable e) {

                           }

                           @Override
                           public void onComplete() {

                           }
                       }));
```

Comment: The error message refers to `MaybeObserver` at line 190 which is not consistent with what you show in the example (`DisposableMaybeObserver` should work as you posted).

Comment: It seems that not defining the returned objects type was causing this issue. GVillani82's answer was close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ResourceMaybeObserver`:

```
private final CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

String id = authManager.getUserID();

Maybe<Object> maybe = userManager.getUser(id);


disposables.add(maybe
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new ResourceMaybeObserver<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@NonNull Object o) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            }));
```